# How to auto stretch a column of a ListView to fill the containing Grid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have created a ListView made up from 2 columns: "File Name" and "Size (MB)". This ListView is contained in a Grid. Since file names are likely to be longer than file sizes, I want to allot as much width as possible for the 'file name' column without damaging the 'size' column.
In other words, I want the 'size' column to fit its content and the 'file name' column to fill the rest of the grid.

I have been playing with many parameters, but could achieve my goal.

My last try looks like this:

```
                <ListView Name="BrowseFilesListView">                        
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>                        
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>                               
                            <GridViewColumn Header="File Name"> 
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Size (MB)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Size}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not supported in WPF. Maybe you should check out this solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/ListView_layout_manager.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
var gridView = SearchResultsTable.View as GridView;
var columns = new GridViewColumnCollection();
if (gridView != null)
{
    columns = gridView.Columns;
}
var width = BrowseFilesListView.ActualWidth;
var sizeWidth = columns[1].ActualWidth; // columns[0] is the Filename, etc.
const int padding = 10; // slightly hackish
columns[0].Width = width - sizeWidth - padding;
```

I would put it in the view's codebehind, in a Window_Loaded event.  It doesn't check for the filesizes' widths; I am making the assumption that they would be less than that of their header.